# Speed Up MATLAB for Fourier Series For Loop

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, sum, vectorization

I know this topic has been visited a number of times, so apologies in advance. I just cannot get around an inefficient for loop operation and would like your help.

I am implementing a single for loop which sums time domain periodic data. I use the Fourier coefficients I obtain from a previous FFT. My issue is that I need to add additional time domain data to the periodic information so I cannot simply use an inverse FFT operation. I am basically editing the standard discrete Fourier transform (DFT) sum, which is namely:

```
for k = 1:L
    x = x + F(k+1)*exp(1j*(omega(k+1)*t));
end
```

In this series F are my Fourier coefficients, omega is the frequency vector and t is the time vector. I have to alter the sum so that it looks like this:

```
for k = 1:L
    x = x + F(k+1)*exp(1j*(omega(k+1)*t)+1j*k*xt);
end
```

The only change is that I am now including a vector which is a time domain function (for example a sine wave) which I have called xt. The problem is the time domain information must have an extremely fine resolution (a 10 second recording is approximately 5e6 long). I cannot shorten the time length because I require a high frequency resolution. This results in a single function evaluation of approximately 7 hours on my machine (which I have to admit, isn't the greatest). I need to evaluate the function in an optimisation setting, and so a 7 hour function evaluation time is not feasible.

I have tried to vectorize the operation, however the matrices become too large for my computer to handle and MATLAB has been updated to handle for loops more efficiently anyway. I have tried to write my own version of the fast Fourier transform, however because I edit the frequency information in each step certain assumptions which the Cooley and Tukey algorithm require break apart. Does anyone know how I can rewrite the above sum into a more efficient format? I have preallocated the vector as well.

Comment: Here are the numbers: as was stated the time vector is in the order of 1e6 (exactly 1016419). this results in a Fourier coefficient vector of length 524288 (as only half of the Fourier coefficients are necessary). In order to add the first 1000 items my computer takes approximately 62 seconds. L is the number of Fourier coefficients I would like to sum over (in this instance 524288).

Comment: OK that is tough. I don't know if I can improve the code.The hard question is, do you really need all those coefficients? For many applications  discarding some aspects of the data is common.

Comment: You've made your sum recursive...is that what you meant to do?  `for k = 1:L
    x = x + F(k+1)*exp(1j*(omega(k+1)*t)+1j*k*xt);  ## every iteration updates x, and then uses x in the exponential
end`

Comment: That's what I was worried about. The phenomenon I am trying to capture is extremely slight in the overall picture of things (specifically turbine blade vibration in a pressure signal). The blade vibration is Doppler shifted and so I require a frequency resolution of at least 32 kHz to prevent aliasing. In Its current form I have a upper frequency limit of around 52 kHz, so bringing this down to 32 kHz is an option, I would however prefer to maintain as much of the signal as I can.

Comment: Yes I did intend to add a new component in each iteration. I have tried to write it in a recurive format based on the original FFT algorithm, it however failed. A large portion of the addtions are repeated, which is why I thought that an improvement on its current form may be possible. The term 'xt' remains constant in each sum. The equation is in the standard exponential Fourier series format. My additional component alters the phase of each frequency component in the sum.

Comment: If you're interested in very high-frequency components, do you need the low frequencies at all? In other words, your slowest fft component is describing how things change over very slow time scales. You could potentially ignore a lot of that, depending on what the spectrum `F` and the adjustment `xt` are supposed to represent.

Comment: I unfortunately do yes. Say the the rotor is operating at 20 Hz, I would like to capture the effect of xt on the pressure response occurring at the original frequency of 20 Hz. Even though modulation may be occurring at much higher frequencies due to 'xt'.

Comment: There is the option of paralleling the sums because each individual unit summed in independent, however the machine I am working on has only got 2 true cores and 8 GB of RAM. And the improvement will be linear in terms of the number of operations (O(N)).

Answer (score 1):

So, the issues:

- looping is slow, but solves you problem in the available memory;
- vectorization is fast, but eats up your memory;

<del>I can't post code because you give too few details about how your `F`, `omega`, `t` and `xt` look like (i.e. exact sizes and ranges for values),</del> but how about a hybrid solution: you split your problem in frequency intervals that can be vectorized, and you accumulate the partial solution for an entire frequency interval (chunk), instead of each frequency. Something like:

```
    %%
    clear all;  % [!] BEWARE BEFORE EXECUTING, IT DELETES STUFF!!!

    N = 1016419;
    R = 524288;

    t     = linspace(1,10,N);
    F     = 400*rand(1,R) + 200i*rand(1,R);
    omega = 1./(1:R);
    xt    = sin(0.23*t);
    x     = zeros(size(xt));

    U  = 10;
    % ck1 = repmat(1i*t,  U, 1); % trying to be extra clever is
    % ck2 = repmat(1i*xt, U, 1); % not always good for the health
    ck1 = 1i*t;
    ck2 = 1i*xt;
    u0  = 1;
    tic;
    while u0 < R
            u1 = min(u0+U-1,R);

            % x  = x + sum(bsxfun( ...
            %     @times, ...
            %     F(u0+1:u1+1).', ...
            %     exp(omega(u0+1:u1+1).' * ck1 ...
            %       +      (u0+1:u1+1).' * ck2 ...
            %     ) ...
            % ));
            x  = x + sum(bsxfun( ...
                @times, ...
                F(u0+1:u1+1).', ...
                exp(bsxfun(@times, ck1, omega(u0+1:u1+1).') ...
                  + bsxfun(@times, ck2,      (u0+1:u1+1).') ...
                ) ...
            ));
            u0 = u1 + 1;

            fprintf('%d iterations: %.0f sec.\n', u1, toc);
    end;
```

The value of `U` should be small enough so the vectorized version of `xu` contribution fits in memory, and big enough for the vectorization to matter. So you need to experiment a little.

Comment: Here goes: 't' is a time vector of size 1x1016419 running from 0 seconds to 10 seconds. 'F' is a Fourier coefficients vector from an FFT of size 1x524288 thus supplying 524288 individual frequency components. The first frequency component of 'omega' is the DC offset at 0 Hz and runs up until a frequency of about 52 kHz (however in rad/s and not Hz). It is derived from a periodic signal of the same size as 't'. 'xt' is another periodic signal of the same size as 't'.

Comment: I forgot to say that the Fourier components contained in 'F' are complex numbers (magnitudes of the frequency components) and are in the range of [0+0i] to [400 + 200i]. I think that computing the operations in chunks and then adding the chunks together may be a really good way forward.

Comment: I have heard that the addition operation in MATLAB is highly inefficient due to the overhead in checks that must be performed before each addition (i.e. size of the items being summed, their contents and so forth). Is there no way to get around these checks and force a hard sum? This may improve the performance of the original formulation significantly as each iteration does not require to perform the checks.

For instance, is there a way to send the vectors to a pre-compiled script which doesn't use any checks, it just does the hard maths and loops?

Comment: @ChrisChurch I'll try to create minimal example based on your description, and I'll experiment with it. Sorry, I don't know about inefficiencies on MATLAB's addition. I'll be back with answer update.

Comment: In hindsight of attempting a fully vectorised solution, which failed not due to the maths but due to my machine's capacity, I am certain a chunking based methodology may be the way to go. I have looked into MATLABs JIT capability, and so I no longer think that pre-compiling will help much as it is already inherently pre-compiled.

Comment: @ChrisChurch Hi Chris, I updated my code. On my machine it took 69 seconds for a thousand iterations, which means that the calculation will end in approx 10 hours. The U value I put was the highest that I could use (with mem cleared) without going out of memory.

Comment: Hi CST-Link, firstly your solution is greatly appreciated! I wouldn't have thought of chunking it until you mentioned it, so thank you. I'll give your code a go on my machine, however in the original form I already achieve 1000 iterations in 62 seconds (I have a dual core i3 with 8GB of RAM). For interest sake what specs does the machine that you ran this code on have so that I can make a fair comparison?

Comment: @ChrisChurch I have an i5 with 4Gb or RAM, and MATLAB R2012a. And lots of other applications open, sorry, I could not close them during the run.

Comment: I have run your code on my machine, here are the numbers for 1000 iterations: with U = 10 it takes 82 sec, U = 20 it takes 70 sec, U = 40 takes 66 sec and finally U = 80 takes 65 sec. In my original format (the nasty for loop) and using your definitions it takes 46 seconds which is still a fair bit faster than your implementation. Thank you though!

Comment: @ChrisChurch Sorry about that, it was worth a try. Maybe this vectorization is not performant exactly because it deals with large arrays, that they don't fit into a core's cache, so there are a lot of cache misses.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be a vectorised approach to carry out what you want, using [`bsxfun`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).

```
k = 1:L;
x = x + sum(bsxfun(@times, F(k+1), exp(1j*(bsxfun(@times, omega(k+1), permute(t, [2 1])) + bsxfun(@times, k, permute(xt, [2 1]))))), 2).';
```

**Note**: For this solution `F`, `omega`, `k`, `t` and `xt` should all be column vectors, that is `1x?`.

### Explanation

The exponential `exp(1j*(omega(k+1)*t)+1j*k*xt)` is computed first with

```
e = exp(1j*(bsxfun(@times, omega(k+1), permute(t, [2 1])) + bsxfun(@times, k, permute(xt, [2 1]))))
```

which generates a `MxL` matrix where `M` is the length of `t` and `xt`. Next we multiply each column of this by `F` (which is of dimension `1xL`) with

```
Fe = bsxfun(@times, F(k+1), e)
```

which is another `MxL` matrix. Finally we sum along the 2nd dimension (`L`) to produce a `Mx1` vector

```
x = x + sum(Fe, 2).'
```

where `.'` is used to transpose the `Mx1` vector to a `1xM` vector.

Comment: I have tried to implement your solution. I am current getting the error 'Non-Singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other' which means that I may just need to fiddle with the dimensions of the arrays in order to get it to work. If I am successful I will post the improvement in performance. Perhaps the solution can be tweaked by forcing the arrays into the desired shape before your vectorised operation.

Comment: @ChrisChurch I've just finished adding an explanation of the dimensions I used.

Comment: Your solution is elegant, and there is no doubt that it would work. However my machine just crashed due to the working memory being filled to capacity when I implemented it with your suggestions. The solution may have to be 'chunked' in order to cope with my available 8GB of RAM. I may have access to a much larger machine tomorrow to try your solution though. I will post results.

Comment: @ChrisChurch Thanks. The best method for 'chunking' would probably be on `t` and `xt`. If you broke up `k` you need to store more intermediary data and perform more `sum`s. Best of luck with it. Hope you get there.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the solution in a fully vectorised format! I have attempted it before, however wasn't aware of the bsxfun which made the strictly matrix algebra solution quite difficult to achieve given the required operations. If I get it to run straight on the larger machine then I will provide information on the results! I will also give your hints on chunking a thinking through. It makes me think that other parallel solution forms may also help (in terms of chunking). Thank you very much.